# Where to store redux-form success message, and how to display it after onSubmitSuccess?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

I've been reading the documentation and several github issues about the subject, but I can't find a clear answer on how to handle a simple success message, that is returned by the server and display it to the user.

My reduxForm reducer looks like this:

```
form: formReducer.plugin({
    forgotPassword: (state, action) => { // <------ 'forgotPassword' is name of form given to reduxForm()
      switch(action.type) {
        case 'FORGOT_PASSWORD_EMAIL_SENT': {
         return {
            ...state,
            successMessage: action.payload
          };
        }
        default:
          return state;
      }
    }
  })
```

And in my actual form component I have this:

```
.......
onSubmitSuccess: (successMessage, dispatch) => { dispatch({type: 'FORGOT_PASSWORD_EMAIL_SENT', payload: successMessage}) }

// now we connect the component to the Redux store:
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    appcoreData: state.appcoreData
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({
                              doForgotPassword: doForgotPassword
                            }
                            , dispatch);
}

// Decorate the form component
ForgotPassword = reduxForm(formConfig)(ForgotPassword);
ForgotPassword = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ForgotPassword);

export default ForgotPassword;
```

Now, when the form is submitted successfully everything executes correctly, and my state will looks like this **state.form.forgotPassword.successMessage = 'my string'**;  but the components never updates to show the actual message.

That is to say in my Form component, how am I supposed to access this part of the state? It's not passed down as a property so I can't do

const { successMessage } = this.props;

In the console I can see the actions dispatched like so:

```
@@redux-form/SET_SUBMIT_SUCCEDED
FORGOT_PASSWORD_EMAIL_SENT
```

So from inside my form component, what is the correct way to access state.form.forgotPassword.successMessage  and display it to the user?

Answer (score -2):

Try using `formValueSelector()`.
See the example here: https://redux-form.com/6.6.0/examples/selectingFormValues/